# Seam security and prettyfaces redirect to a wrong url after login

Tags: java, jsf, seam3, prettyfaces

When I log in to my page with seam security, it redirects me to /WEB-INF/pages/index.xhtml instead of simply /. This is a snippet of my @ViewConfig:

```
public interface PagesConfig {
    public static final String PAGES_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/pages/";

    static enum Pages {
        @ViewPattern(PAGES_PREFIX + "index.xhtml")
        @UrlMapping(pattern = "/")
        @LoggedIn
        @LoginView(PAGES_PREFIX + "login.xhtml")
        INDEX,

        @ViewPattern(PAGES_PREFIX + "login.xhtml")
        @UrlMapping(pattern = "/login")
        LOG_IN,
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Do you know where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SEAMFACES-193

And I think I've found a fix, so I filed a pull request on github:
https://github.com/seam/faces/pull/75